# How to run bitcoin core in the cloud with virtual server?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, client, full-node, cloud-mining

can you please explain to me, or link me to other understandable sources, how you can use bitcoin core with a cloud provider?

My intent is to not physically have an own server but to use a cloud server.
Lets say AWS as a provider.

Lets say I bought my cloud server package. What is next? How can I put the entire bitcoin blockchain on it and make it function like a full node ?  So that I can always forward to this cloud server whenever I do a transaction with Electrum on another computer?

Thanks

Comment: You can just spin up a Linux/Windows VM and then remote login into it (putty or RDP). Setup your Bitcoin node as if you were to do it on a normal physical desktop.

Comment: There is little point in using a full node if you're not running it yourself as you'll be trusting the cloud provider to run it honestly for you. If that's an acceptable risk to you, maybe using a lightweight client instead is acceptable too.

Comment: thx both! Pieter but you also trust your ISP when you use your internet at home, right? your ISP has even more power than the cloud provider. There will always be trusted parties... only the party may change from time to time.

Comment: Your ISP can't steal your money, make you incorrectly think you received money, ... while a cloud provider can. All your ISP can do (when you use a full node) is make you lose synchronization with the network, which will start looking increasingly suspicious (unless they also have significant hashpower). You're right that there is trust involved, but the damage your ISP can do is trivial compared to a node running in the cloud.

Comment: @pieter-wuille- got u! what should one do if he wants to prevent censorship then, is VPN helping out against ISP knowing that u run a bitcoin core full node wallet?